# ReportProgress doesn't call progressChanged with tasks in c#

Tags: c#, task, backgroundworker

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        int currentProgress=-1;

        while (currentProgress<length)
        {
            currentProgress=Worker.progress;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(currentProgress);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            length = Worker.UrlList.Count;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ix = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar1.Value = ix;
        lblText.Text =ix+" %";
    }
```

I wrote a program to download page sources by reading a file have about 1000 URLs. so I used Tasks to download pages async. here `Worker.progress` is the currently executed URL amount. though the debuger hits the `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(currentProgress);` it never enter to the `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`.

```
 private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        t.makeUrlList(inputFile);

        backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        t.RunTasks();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

background worker initializes when start button clicks...

here is where my tasks are created....

```
public void RunTasks()
    {
        if (numOfTasks > UrlList.Count)
            numOfTasks=UrlList.Count-1;
       Task[] t = new Task[numOfTasks];
        int j = 0;
        while ( j < UrlList.Count-1)
        {

           for (int i = 0; (i < t.Count())&&(j<UrlList.Count-1); i++)
            {


                try
                {
                    if (t[i].IsCompleted || t[i].IsCanceled || t[i].IsFaulted)
                    {
                        t[i] = Task.Run(() => FindWIN(j));
                        j++;
                        progress = j;                            
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException ex)
                {
                    t[i] = Task.Run(() => FindWIN(j));
                    j++;
                    progress = j;
                }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And I have also set the WorkerReportsProgress to true..

Comment: Can you maybe post the code which initializes the BackgroundWorker? Otherwise we can only guess at likely causes, rather the identify the actual problem in your code.

Comment: I came with an odd explanation. Form1 is the main thread that runs the UI thread. so if we want to display progress on the progress bar, we have to run the main thread inside backgroundworker thread(in dowork method). otherwise we cannot access the progressbar from background worker.

Comment: sorry. I added the background worker initialization method.

Comment: Tasks are created for .net in the recent past. so I think this might be a bug..?

Comment: Your t.RunTasks() call is going to block the GUI thread. You won't see any updates at all. It's not a C# bug - there are quite a few problems with your code. If nobody's given a good answer, I'll try to post a detailed response later today.

Comment: aha you are 100% correct... that is what happened. GUI was freeze. please point out. I'll re-correct them. but why debugger doesn't hit the progressChanged method but the dowork method.?

Comment: See sample code added below - should give you a good start! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the demo code below. This is mostly untested, and certainly isn't 'production standard', but it should give you a good start!

1. It uses a `ConcurrentQueue` to hold the list of URLs to be processed. This is threadsafe, and makes life a lot easier.
2. It has a configurable number of urls and tasks. It's best not to make 1000 tasks, but instead have a queue of work items, and a smaller pool of Tasks which 'pull items' off the queue until it's empty. This means you can performance test different numbers of Tasks and find the best value for your problem.
3. It uses Invoke when updating the progress bar - this avoids the cross-thread exception.
4. No `BackgroundWorker` - just `TaskFactory` and `Task`

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       private const int UrlCount = 1000;
       private const int taskCount = 10;
       private ConcurrentQueue<string> urlList;
       private List<Task> taskList;

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void ResetQueue()
       {
           // fake up a number of strings to process
           urlList = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, UrlCount)
                     .Select(i => "http://www." + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".com"));
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           ResetQueue();
           var taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
           // start a bunch of tasks
           taskList = Enumerable.Range(0, taskCount).Select(i => taskFactory.StartNew(() => ProcessUrl()))
                                 .ToList();
       }

       void ProcessUrl()
       {
           string current;

           // keep grabbing items till the queue is empty
           while (urlList.TryDequeue(out current))
           {
               // run your code
               FindWIN(current);

               // invoke here to avoid cross thread issues
               Invoke((Action)(() => UpdateProgress()));
           }
       }

       void FindWIN(string url)
       {
           // your code here
           // as a demo, sleep a sort-of-random time between 0 and 100 ms
           Thread.Sleep(Math.Abs(url.GetHashCode()) % 100);
       }

       void UpdateProgress()
       {
           // work out what percentage of the queue is processed
           progressBar1.Value = (int)(100 - ((double)urlList.Count * 100.0 / UrlCount));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i want to upvote. but it requires minimum 15 reputation. since i'm new i only have 13 now. if you upvote my question I can reach 15 and I can upvote you :)

Comment: Made minor edit to make the create list of tasks a field rather than a local variable

Answer (score 3):

If you want to BackgroundWorker supports updating progress information, the value of WorkerReportsProgress should be set to true . If this property is true , the user code can call ReportProgress for initiating event ProgressChanged .

**Background worker initialization:-**

```
 backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
 backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
 backgroundWorker1.DoWork+=backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
 backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged+=backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
            int currentProgress = -1;

            decimal length=1000;
            while (currentProgress < length)
            {
                currentProgress = Worker.progress;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(currentProgress);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                length = Worker.UrlList.Count;
            }
 }

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)        {
            int ix = e.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBar1.Value = ix;
            lblText.Text = ix + " %";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set [WorkerReportsProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your worker to true on initialization stage.

Comment: My thoughts too, but perhaps this might be better as a comment, as it's phrased as another question rather than an answer.

Comment: Don't quite agree, in my mind commenting needed if I want to get some more info, but when I'm sure where is the problem - I use answer.

Comment: I see your point, and it's valid. But it's the phrasing I disagree with, not the content. I'm suggesting that you maybe should have written an *answer*, rather than a *question*. That is, *You should set your property to true*, not *did you set your property to true?*

Comment: I guess Baldric found the reason of your problem: you are doing too much job in the UI thread (t.RunTask call) and then unload the app, so you don't see anything new in the UI.